# Is there any way for grouping cases in MySQL CASE statements?

Tags: mysql, switch-statement, coding-style, case-statement, code-readability

Is there any short form for writing MySQL CASE statements as in PHP switch? For example, if i have:

```
SELECT
    CASE Type
        WHEN 1 THEN "A"
        WHEN 5 THEN "B"
        WHEN 10 THEN "B"
        WHEN 20 THEN "B"
        WHEN 30 THEN "B"
        WHEN 300 THEN "C"
        ELSE "-"
    END TypeDesc
```

In PHP syntax we can write it in brief:

```
switch ($Type) {
    case 1: $TypeDesc = 'A'; break; 
    case 5:
    case 10:
    case 20:
    case 30: $TypeDesc = 'B'; break; 
    case 300: $TypeDesc = 'C'; break;
    default: $TypeDesc = '-'; }
```

I tried:

```
WHEN 5 OR 10 OR 20 OR 30 THEN "B"
```

and

```
WHEN IN(5, 10, 20, 30) THEN "B"
```

and these two:

```
WHEN 5
WHEN 10
WHEN 20
WHEN 30 THEN "B"

WHEN 5 THEN
WHEN 10 THEN
WHEN 20 THEN
WHEN 30 THEN "B"
```

But i get incorrect result or error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
case when <condition>
```

instead of

```
case <variable> when <value>
```

like this

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN "A"
         WHEN Type < 300 THEN "B"
         WHEN Type = 300 THEN "C"
         ELSE "-"
    END TypeDesc
```